# I can't change the compileSdkVersion from 28 to 31. if I change it, it displays new errors. how to fix the it by any other ways? please assist me

Tags: react-native

While I'm using the command ".\gradlew assembleDebug"
I faced an error that I mentioned below

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-28).
> Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd09748713ce4574fd63858d9ec7f9e6\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

### Environment

react-native 0.50.3
Java 11
Node 20

### SdkVersions

compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28

### Conflicts dependencies

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3"

### Android Gradle Plugin

classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")

### Gradle Distribution

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

**I can't change the compileSdkVersion from 28 to 31. because if I change it, it displays new errors. how to fix the error by any other ways? please assist me.
**